# Why can I execute an Android application with which is compiled against API 17 on a phone running API level 10?

Tags: android

I am building an Android application which I compile against API-17: project.properties contains

```
target=android-17
```

I am slightly confused because I can download and execute the application on an Android phone running Gingerbread 3.3.6, API 10. Can perhaps someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to run it on API 10 as your `android:minSdkVersion` would be less than 10. It is 
an integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

To differ between `target` in project.properties and `android:targetSdkVersion`

`target=android-sdk` version in project.properties file indicates Eclipse will not allow use methods or classes from sdk higher than this one.

`android:targetSdkVersion` attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions

Source: [What is the difference between the 'target' settings in the 'project.properties' file and the 'android:targetSdkVersion' tag in the manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072347/what-is-the-difference-between-the-target-settings-in-the-project-properties)

Comment: Is the `target` setting inside project.properties the same as `android:targetSdkVersion` in the manifest XML file?

Answer (score 2):

Because target=android-17 is compilation target not a MIN-SDK.
Min-sdk version will be Android 2.2 so you are able to download and execute on 3.3.6, API 10

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are valid.

I'll only add that there's one condition to that: That the code of that application should be written in API-10 compatible code. The application shouldn't call classes or methods that are not defined in API-10 otherwise it will crash when doing so.

Then, Android has many way for developers to work around compatibility, such as the support libraries and detecting device version to write specific compatibility code.