# Not targeting the latest versions of Android 2.2

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not targeting the latest versions of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431722/not-targeting-the-latest-versions-of-android)

I have a warning when trying to test theme on latest Android SDK Package 4.2.
Here is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.thepikopaper.sdd.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".PlayButton"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >  
            <action android:name="com.thepikopaper.sdd.PLAYBUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can you should test your app on the latest android version you can find (and all older versions). And use this version as targetSdkVersion. [You can read here about it.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

You also can ignore this message if you are OK with everything.

Answer (score 0):

It ,may be, says that you don't use  last API (API Level 17).