# Lowering minSdkVersion when using APIs introduced after, fails to cause errors

Tags: android

I created an app compatible with API level 14+.  I want to now make it compatible with API level 10+. I know for a fact I am using API calls introduced in 14, so I was planning on lowering the minSdkVersion first, and then fix the errors that it caused.

The only problem is, when I lowered the minSdkVersion in the manifest, no errors are thrown.  It used to throw errors when I did this, but now it isn't for some reason.

Is there a way to force Eclipse to check my API calls and make sure they are compatible with the current minSdkVersion?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a device in AVD running API level 10 and see if it fails there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click over the project in Package Explorer, and choose Android Tools > Run Lint.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the minSdkVersion it won't change what sdk the app in compiled against, only the api levels that the application can be installed on.

If you want to compile against a lower sdk change the targetSdkVersion.

Links: [Difference between "Build Target SDK" in Eclipse and android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938348/difference-between-build-target-sdk-in-eclipse-and-androidtargetsdkversion-in)
and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html also [Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)